# How to setup custom domain with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I've followed the instruction and now I can access my GAE application with `http://www.mydomain.com`, but `http://mydomain.com` is not accessible - google (!) returns error 404. What I've missed in the setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google App Engine doesn't support naked domains](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=777&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log), [you need to forward request from](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2518373) http://mydomain.com to http://www.mydomain.com.

Comment: Thanks! I've also found this instruction - http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2518373